# Hello world of FBJS

Tags: fbjs

I'm trying to start off using FBJS, and I can't figure this out. The documentation on developer.facebook.com seems so limited and hard to sort through I can't figure out where to find info on this.

Anyway, I'm just trying to do the hello world application shown on facebook

```
<script> 
<!-- 
function random_int(lo, hi) { 
   return Math.floor((Math.random() * (hi - lo)) + lo); 
} 

function hello_world(obj) { 
   var r = random_int(0, 255), b = random_int(0, 255), g = random_int(0, 255); 
   var color = r+', '+g+', '+b;
   obj.setStyle('color', 'rgb('+color+')'); 
} 
//--> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="hello_world(this); return false;">Hello World!</a>
```

I keep getting the error saying that the object has no method setStyle. I thought FBJS was supposed to be part of facebook. Do I have to include fbjs in my canvas url?

Oh, and here's the url: http://apps.facebook.com/thedivide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your canvas app is in iframe mode. This means you can and should use normal JavaScript. If you want to use FBJS change your application to FBML mode. You can do this from you application setting in the *Facebook Integration* section. See the attached screenshot:

[image: FBML mode]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [sandbox](http://www.fbjs.facebook.com/) and it should work.

Comment: how do i open this app in the sandbox?

Comment: You just do it like you would "normally" when logged on the "normal" facebook.com.